# Magento 2: Checkbox Validation

Tags: magento2, frontend, form-validation

I have displayed a frontend form. The form has a checkbox field and it is a mandatory field. But the validation for the field is not working. Please help.

This is my phtml file:

```
<div class="field interested required">
            <label class="label" for="interested">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Interested in:') ?></span>
            </label>  
               <div class="radio_interested control">
                    <div class="radio_option_interested">
                        <input name="interested[]" id="option-1" value="1" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox"  data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                        <label for="option-1" class="radio_label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('SAmple Text1') ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio_option_interested">
                            <input name="interested[]" id="option-2" value="2" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox"  data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                            <label for="option-2" class="radio_label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sample Text2') ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio_option_interested">
                            <input name="interested[]" id="option-3" value="3" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox"  data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                            <label for="option-3" class="radio_label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sample Text3') ?></label>
                    </div>
                   <div class="radio_option_interested"> 
                           <input name="interested[]" id="option-4" value="4" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox"  data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                           <label for="option-4" class="radio_label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('SAmple TExt4') ?> </label>
                   </div>

             </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: give this class `"checkbox required"` to input element like `class="input-checkbox checkbox required"` and then check

Comment: Validation is working. But the validation message is displayed here. Please refer the screenshot. http://i.prntscr.com/90177add6fc34ae69d4c04d07d4ebf33.png

Comment: I want to display the message after all checkbox field values.

Comment: Out of 4 checkbox field values, any one of the value needs to be selected. So, the validation message needs to be displayed after all checkbox field values.

Comment: it looks like there is no ability to do it out of box, look here vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/jquery/jquery.validate.js in check() function - `element = this.validationTargetFor(this.clean(element));`, even if you add validation rules on last checkbox, this line makes `element` as first by name

Answer (score 0):

4 years late but in case anyone else finds this, you have to add a div with class 'control' around the input to show the validation message.

e.g.

```
<div class="control">
    <div class="field choice">
        <label class="checkbox-label label grey">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox required" name="fieldname" />
            <span>I am required!</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```